# Total angular momentum of a disk around a fixed axis

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

For **total** angular momentum of a disk traveling around a fixed point(pivot) at angular velocity $\Omega$, is the rotation of the disk around its own axis ($\omega$) relevant in the equation?

No need for a complicated explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can write

$$\vec{L}_{Tot}=\vec{L}_{CM}+\vec{L}^*$$

where $\vec{L}_{CM}$ is the angular momentum of the center of mass and $\vec{L}^*$ is the angular momentum viewed from the center of mass.